# How to take at template table one time photo next time string value

Tags: python, django

I want to make table where second element in every row is photo. Like here: http://www.uefa.com/worldcup/season=2014/standings/

I have all my values in list. In list, third element is photo's url. Other variables are just strings. How to write it in Django template?

Here is my code:

```
<table>
{% for row in data%}
    <tr>
    {% for value in row %}
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

I hope you will understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your {{ value }} for that second element should be a path (relative or absolute) to an image resource. If this data is defined by a model within your Django project, make sure the field is set correctly in models.py--it should be a FileField or ImageField. With those, you get a callable URL property. Then in your template, something along these lines:

```
<table>
{% for row in data%}
    <tr>
    {% for value in row %}

        {% if value.url %}
            <td><img src="{{ value.url }}" alt="..."></td>
        {% else %}
            <td>{{ value }}</td>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Did I undestand corectly? I will need to use namedtuple in my views?